# Do we have model binding in web service methods?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, jquery, webforms

I want to use `jQuery` ajax in `ASP.NET WebForms` and I want to directly call a web service method:

```
$.ajaxWrapper('/services.asmx/createprofile', {
firstName = firstName, 
lastName = lastName,  
city = city, 
state = state, 
address = address, 
postalCode = postalCode, 
tell = tell, 
cellPhone = cellPhone, 
isCompany = isCompany }, function(r){
   // success callback; return value is in r parameter.
});
```

Note: line breaks are for demonstration purpose only.

However, since the number of fields are even more than this, and all of'em are required, I don't want to create a web service method to get everything as parameter:

```
[WebMethod]
public bool CreateProfile (string firstName, 
string lastName, 
string city, 
string state, 
string address, 
string postalCode, 
string tell, 
string cellPhone, 
bool isCompany)
{

}
```

Is there any way like ASP.NET MVC model binding to let the framework does the trick? In other words, can I write my web service code this way:

```
[WebMethod]
public bool CreateProfile (UserProfile profile)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but I believe you can just define a UserProfile class (make it public) in the service method's class, (make sure to use getters and setters and give it a default empty constructor the same as you do in MVC) and it will figure things out.

```
[WebMethod] 
public bool CreateProfile (UserProfile profile) 
{
    ....  
} 

public class UserProfile 
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. However, I'm not seeking to find an example here, as I can do the experiment myself. Rather I want a kind of explanation why it supports/doesn't support model binding. :)

Comment: That was not your question. But - the serivce method receives SOAP-formatted XML and then deserializes it and the asp.net framework then binds it to the model.